# Companies of La Paz Stock Exchange

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, bolivia

Where can I see a list of companies listed on the La Paz Stock Exchange (Bolsa Boliviana de Valores or BBV)?

Comment: Go to the exchange's web site and see if they list the companies that trade on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of companies on the first page of the daily resume of the BBV:
https://www.bbv.com.bo/Media/Default/Home/Resumen.pdf

A separate list will give you the company names, since this list is only abbrevations:
https://www.bbv.com.bo/Media/Default/InformacionBursatil/codigos.pdf